# Unknown type name 'NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN' Error in CLError and CLErrorDomain

Tags: c#, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am getting this error after exporting my project from Unity. My unity version is 2019.4.20f1 and Xcode version is 12.0
I am receiving these errors pointing to two files 'CLErrorDomain.h' and 'CLError.h'
Although after exporting the same project the Android apk is working fine. Is there any issue with the pods or my Xcode version?